# Create Dynamic Query in SAP using Table Function

Tags: hana-sql-script, table-functions, amdp

I am trying to create Dynamic SQL query using Table Function, so that it can be consumed in ABAP CDS views. For same I have developed an ABAP Class & defined a method "Get_data".

```
CLASS-METHODS get_data FOR TABLE FUNCTION ztablefunction.
```

I am expecting below results, I am getting table names from field .
for each Condition record number it should go to its respective table and fetch few fields.

- NOTE: Every table will have different structures only Condition
  Record no. will always be available, e.g. Table A900 may have Sales
  Org field, but A912 might not have Sales Org field

[image]

Below image depicts data in Dynamic Tables (Table Fields in Table A)

[image]

Below image depicts output I am expecting.

[image]

```
CLASS zcl_fiori_test DEFINITION
  PUBLIC
  FINAL
  CREATE PUBLIC .
    
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES if_amdp_marker_hdb.
    
    CLASS-METHODS  get_data FOR TABLE FUNCTION ztablefunction.
    
  PROTECTED SECTION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.
    
    
CLASS zcl_fiori_test IMPLEMENTATION.


  METHOD get_data BY DATABASE FUNCTION
                      FOR HDB
                      LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
                      OPTIONS READ-ONLY
                      USING zcds_test  dd03l.
    
    declare tabnamearr string;
    declare lv_knumharr string;
    declare iv_count integer;
    declare i integer;
    declare lv_query string;
    declare lv_kunnr string;
    declare lv_vkorg string;
    
    
    it_cdhdr = select :p_mandt as client,
        conditiontype as cond_type,
        '' as valid_start,
        '' as valid_end,
        changedocobjectclass,
        changedocobject,
        changedocument,
        changetransactioncode,
        cdhdrcreationdate,
        creationdate,
        keycombcondrec from zcds_test;
    
    select count( * ) into iv_count from :it_cdhdr;
    
    it_sel = select changedocobject, keycombcondrec from :it_cdhdr;
    
    it_final1 = select
        '' as mandt,
        '' as kappl,
        '    ' as kschl,
        '    ' as vkorg,
        '' as vtweg,
        '          ' as kunnr,
        '' as matnr,
        '' as kfrst,
        '' as datbi,
        '' as datab,
        '' as kbstat,
        '          ' as knumh
        from dummy; 
    
    it_kunnr = select '          ' as knumh, '          ' as kunnr  from dummy;

    it_vkorg = select  '          ' as knumh, '    ' as vkorg from dummy;'''
    
    for i in 1..iv_count do
    
        tabnamearr = :it_sel.keycombcondrec[i] ;
        lv_knumharr = :it_sel.changedocobject[i];
    
    
        IF exists(select *
              from    dd03l
              where  tabname = tabnamearr
                     and fieldname = 'KUNNR'
                      ) then
             lv_kunnr =  'select knumh, kunnr from ' || tabnamearr || ' where knumh = ' || lv_knumharr;
             EXECUTE immediate lv_kunnr INTO it_kunnr;
    
        END if;

        it_cdsview1 = SELECT a.changedocobjectclass,
        a.changedocobject,
        a.changedocument,
        a.changetransactioncode,
        a.cdhdrcreationdate,
        a.creationdate,
        a.keycombcondrec,
        cust.kunnr
         from zcds_test as a
        left join :it_kunnr as cust on a.changedocobject = cust.knumh;
    
    
        if exists(select *
              from    dd03l
              where  tabname = tabnamearr
                     and fieldname = 'VKORG'
                      ) then

            lv_vkorg =  ' it_vkorg = select knumh, vkorg from ' || tabnamearr || ' where knumh = ' || lv_knumharr;

            EXECUTE immediate lv_vkorg into it_vkorg;

        END if;
    
        it_cdsview2 = SELECT a.changedocobjectclass,
        a.changedocobject,
        a.changedocument,
        a.changetransactioncode,
        a.cdhdrcreationdate,
        a.creationdate,
        a.keycombcondrec,
        salesorg.vkorg from zcds_Test as a
    
        left join :it_vkorg as salesorg on a.changedocobject = salesorg.knumh;
    
    end for;
    
    return
        select <from Final Output table that should be matched with structure of Table Function>
    
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

Above code, I am not able to store data in temporary table as it does not support.

For alternative I have created structure/table using DUMMY table.
But data is getting replaced with new data.

It might be a wrong approach, kindly suggest correct approach to achieve same.
Please let me know, if you need more information